# Differential topology and/or geometry from the viewpoint of Cauchy completions

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, category-theory

According to [an nLab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Karoubi+envelope) that I don't really understand, if we take the "Cauchy completion" of the category $\mathbf{C}$ whose objects are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and whose morphisms are smooth mappings, the result is the category of smooth manifolds. This sounds super cool, and I'd like to understand it better.

> **Question.** Does anyone know of a good introductory article on differential topology and/or geometry from the viewpoint of Cauchy completions, with lots of good handholding and intuition?

Comment: Someone else asked essentially [the same question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/224569/11640).

Comment: @ZhenLin, thanks, this is a clear duplicate.

Comment: You might want to have a look at Lurie's DAG V, where this kind of perspective is developed further.

Comment: @Adeel, thanks!